# How to split this url accept multiple sms gateways

Tags: php, sms, gateway

I am currently making a script that will be able to send sms via the http api of multiple sms gateways.But my problem is how to extract the api details from the url.

Here is what I am trying to do :

A simple html form where a user can paste the API details given by an sms gateway. eg

**http://www.mysmsgateway.com/s/smsapi.php?username=xxx&password=xxx&sender=Mybrand&recipient=234808xxxxxxx,2348030000000&message=yourmessagehere**

The url is recieved via  php, and the api details are extracted, for sending sms

The  problem I have is that the HTTP API url format of these gateways are always slightly different from each other.

Lokk at the one below

**http://www.estoresms.com/smsapi.php?username=user&password=1234&sender=@@sender@@&recipient=@@recipient@@&message=@@message@@&**

Here is the code I'm currently writing

**

```
   <?php
    if(isset($_POST['url']))
    {

     $url=$_POST['url'];
     $splt=explode('?',$url);
     //var_dump($splt);
     $result=file_get_contents($url);
     echo($result);

     }
    ?>
    <form action="<?php  echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?> " method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="url"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>

    </form>**
```

I know that the html is not yet complete

Comment: my code works for one but not the other in the examples given above

Comment: if your sending,, i don't understand why you are processing existing urls, and not creating your own